# Why clearing PATH in windows CMD prompt makes it close immediatly?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, cmd.exe, environment-variables

Consider these 2 versions of a cmd script.

**First Version** (overrides PATH)

```
set PATH=%USERPROFILE%.cargo\bin;%USERPROFILE%.rustup;
%~d1
cd "%~p1"
call cmd
```

**Second Version** (add some path to PATH)

```
set PATH=%PATH%;%USERPROFILE%.cargo\bin;%USERPROFILE%.rustup;
%~d1
cd "%~p1"
call cmd
```

In the **first case**, the CMD prompt open when I double click the script, but it is **closed shortly after**, in the second case it stays open.

Why it is closed?

(note both are Scripts.cmd that gets double clicked, if that matters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your Default Path in Windows 10 Advanced System Settings. It is a very long path that includes all the folders Windows needs to run.

In your first example above, you cleared all that out, so Windows could not find what it needed and closed.

In your second example, you included the Default Path with your new paths. This is the correct way to do it and Windows can continue to find its programs that it needs.

Use the second method always.

[image]

Comment: since CMD was already started before editing the PATH, shouldn't CMD run anyway?

Comment: Once you edit the path to clear where Windows finds CMD, it is not likely Windows can find it. Just use the correct Path setup to avoid this problem

Comment: Using path to change the system path does not take effect until the cmd shell is closed and a new one started ...

Comment: I would think so too, but it closed on the author, and I really think keeping the path or adjusting it, rather than clearing it is the best way to go.